# Does wkwebview support HTML5 capture attribute?

Tags: html, ios, media, wkwebview

As the title said, does it support it? [Here is the MDN Documentation of it (Incomplete)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/capture) and [Here is the caniuse browsers support list](https://caniuse.com/#feat=html-media-capture).

However, none of them talked about wkwebview. Does it support this attribute? If so, it would help tremendously.

Thanks for answering this question beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments, apparently it is supported, only if an UDID is registered (how this is registered don't ask me, it was through a vendor. I don't have the details.)

It opens the camera and after you took a pic or a video it behaves like any common file picker.

To implement this in one of those html qr/barcode scanners it needs to have the ability to scan an image. But hey, better than nothing right?

Comment: to also add, it seems the file caught from the camera is temporary without any url, if you don't like to synchronously post it like old times, use JS's URL api to create a temp url for it.

Comment: also, also, sometimes qr reader library with the ability to decode an image doesn't actually transform it to base64 first before decoding. In that case, use JS Filereader api.    
Or instead, use [this library](https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode) instead. Heck of a lot faster.